# How to check if an object has a stored property?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection

I need to check if an object's class has a member which could be used for assigning a value. Let's say there's a class:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

  var myVar : AnyObject!

  // ...
}
```

I tried this objC style but properties are a different beast in Swift and second line always returns false:

```
let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
let hasClassMember = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar:"))

if hasClassMember {

  myClass.performSelector("setMyVar:", withObject: "Context" as! AnyObject)
}
```

I assume Swift doesn't have a powerful reflection as ObjC has, but is there any solution?

**UPDATE** It turns out my code works, however I have simplified it for demo purposes. The weird part is respondsToSelector stops working as soon as I change the type of myVar to be an instance of some custom class, let say ClassB. Feels it a bit magic... :)

**UPDATE2** Finally I found the problem. I haven't wrote the full code, thought the problem is elsewhere, anyway, here's the full code. MyClass variable is actually a type of some other AnotherClass which implements AnotherClassProtocol

```
protocol AnotherClassProtocol {
  //…
}

class AnotherClass: AnotherClassProtocol {
  //…
}

class MyClass: NSObject {

  var myVar : AnotherClass!
  // ...
}
```

This was causing myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar:")) always return false. It turns out the problem was because I omitted extending of  NSObject in my AnotherClass declaration. It starts working as expected after I fixed that:

```
class AnotherClass: NSObject, AnotherClassProtocol {
  //…
}
```

I'm still learning Swift and thought NSObject is not needed as the compiler was not complaining and everything extend from NSObject anyway (at least in ObjC). Well, I'm glad I found this nasty bug.

Comment: I tried this code in a playground and it worked correctly for me. I had to remove the as! AnyObject and I also remove the `selector()` around the `setMyVar:` as it isn't needed. `hasClassMember` was also true/false based on the property name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import Foundation
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var myVar1 : AnyObject!

    // ...
}

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
let hasClassMemberMyVar1 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar1:")) // true
let hasClassMemberMyVar2 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar2:")) // false
```

it works for me ...

UPDATE, based on OP notes

```
import Foundation
class C:NSObject {}
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var myVar1 : C? // Objective-C representable
    var i: Int = 0  // Objective-C representable
    var j: Int? = 10
}

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
let hasClassMemberMyVar1 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar1:")) // true
let hasClassMemberMyVar2 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setMyVar2:")) // false
let hasClassMemberI = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setI:")) // true
let hasClassMemberJ = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setJ:")) // false, because Optional<Int> is not representable in Objective-C !!!
print(myClass.i.dynamicType, myClass.j.dynamicType) // Int Optional<Int>
```

with class type properties only

```
import Foundation
class C:NSObject {}
class C1 {}
class MyClass: NSObject {
    var c : C?
    var cO1: C = C()
    var cO2: C!
    var c1: C1 = C1()
    var c2: C1?
    var c3: C1!
}

let myClass: MyClass = MyClass()
let hasClassMemberC = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setC:")) // true
let hasClassMemberCO1 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setCO1:")) // true
let hasClassMemberCO2 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setCO2:")) // true
let hasClassMemberC1 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setC1:")) // false, class C1 is not Objective-C representable ...
let hasClassMemberC2 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setC2:")) // false, Optional<C1> is not Objective-C representable ...
let hasClassMemberC3 = myClass.respondsToSelector(Selector("setC3:")) // false, ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<C1> is not Objective-C representable ...
```

Comment: Looks like it's working with myVar being a type of AnyObject, however it doesn't if I would change its type. Please check my update.

Comment: @Centurion if type of myVar1 inherits from NSObject, it should still work. Take in account, that Selector works only for dynamic binding, so your class property should be Objective-C representable too.

Comment: @Centurion i added example where all properties are some class (reference type)

Comment: Thanks, please check updated question. You was right, it should work and I did a mistake.

Answer (score 10):

**A slightly nicer way than checking for selectors would be to use a protocol.**

```
protocol MyClassProtocol {
    var myVar : AnyObject! {get set}
}

class MyClass: NSObject, MyClassProtocol {
     var myVar : AnyObject!
     // ...
}

...

let c = MyClass()

if let conformingMyClass = c as? MyClassProtocol { // returns true
    print("yay")
    conformingMyClass.myVar = "Context"
} else {
    print("nay")
}
```

This way it's a lot more explicit which classes do and don't have your property and you don't have to muck about with selectors (much more Swift-y).

Comment: Hm, this approach seems difficult to use with TDD, where you should often test for a variable existing before it's implemented, no?

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3 version of Ryan Huubert's answer:

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var myVar : AnyObject!
    // ...
}

let myClass = MyClass()

myClass.responds(to: Selector("myVar")) // returns true
myClass.responds(to: Selector("myVar:")) // returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    var myVar : AnyObject!
    // ...
}

let myClass = MyClass()

myClass.respondsToSelector("myVar") // returns true
myClass.respondsToSelector("myVar:") // returns false
```